# Passing arguments to a new thread in OS-iii as void pointer

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded

Some background: I am reading the uC/OS-III Users Manual by Micrium, and following that guide I am programming in C with IAR Embedded Workbench IDE.

The code is from some examples provided with the book written for the uC-Eval-STM32F107 development board. It is creating a new thread, and passing arguments by a void pointer. I'm familiar with void pointers and passing arguments to threads.

A kernel function is called to create a new thread:

```
OSTaskCreate( ... );
```

Then inside the function definition they do something I don't know how to describe:

```
static  void  AppTaskStart (void *p_arg)
{
    CPU_INT32U  cpu_clk_freq;
    CPU_INT32U  cnts;
    OS_ERR      err;
    CPU_TS  ts;


   p_arg = p_arg;

    ...
}
```

or I have also see in other example the code looks like this:

```
(void *)p_arg;
```

What are they doing and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 p_arg = p_arg;
```

or

```
(void *)p_arg;
```

are put there to suppress a warning regarding the unused variable `p_arg`.